# Tensorflow-Keras vector normalise output layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My model outputs a direction vector in 3d space so I do not care about the magnitude of the vector.
How can I vector normalise the output layer so that the loss function doesn't care about the magnitude either?

Model:

```py
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(17,), dtype=np.float64),
        layers.Dense(9, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(9, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(9, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(9, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(3) # output layer I want to vector normalise
    ]
)
```

Alternatively would it be possible to specify for the loss function to only consider the angle between the vectors as loss?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was looking for:

```
tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity
```